# Mongodb connectionString can't connect

Tags: mongodb

I can connect via **Mongodb COMPASS** using my username and password but apparently i can't connect it to my website.

`mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb` works fine in connection string but not atlas/online cluster

```
{"connectionString":"mongodb+srv://myuser:mypass@thiscluster.azure.mongodb.net/mydb?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
    ,"secret":""}
```

Error :

```
Server listening on port 3000
Unhandled rejection MongoError: not authorized on admin to execute command { lis
tIndexes: "sessions", cursor: {  } }
    at Function.MongoError.create (C:\Users\user\Documents\GitHub\meanie\serv
er\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\error.js:31:11)
    at queryCallback (C:\Users\user\Documents\GitHub\meanie\server\node_modul
es\mongodb-core\lib\cursor.js:212:36)
    at C:\Users\user\Documents\GitHub\meanie\server\node_modules\mongodb-core
\lib\connection\pool.js:469:18
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:11)
```

I am using [MEANIE STACK BLOG](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/10/29/meanie-mean-stack-blogging-platform)

Reference : *Cloud mongodb guide*
mongodb+srv://:@thiscluster.azure.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority

Other reference : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/

Comment: Looks like you may have restricted permissions on the Atlas server? Did you create the user or did someone else?

Comment: @JoeDrumgoole I have full access with the database. i have set it up as dbadmin settings as well as readandwrite. where did I do wrong?

Comment: Are you connecting to the right database? Can you post a small standalone program that works locally and fails on atlas?

Comment: @JoeDrumgoole hello, i solved it just now, i was using an old version of node and the connectionString's mongo+srv can't be parsed/read by it. answer posted below

Answer (score 1):

**SOLVED**

config.json / node's `"connectionString"` can't be parsed using `mongo+srv://user:pw@thiscluster.mongodb.com/mydb?thisoptions`

node version i'm using is `2.2 12`

fixed via :

```
"connectionString":"mongodb://user:pass@test-shard-00-00-sample.azure.mongodb.net:27017,test-shard-00-01-sample.azure.mongodb.net:27017,test-shard-00-02-sample.azure.mongodb.net:27017/THISDB?ssl=true&replicaSet=Test-shard-0&authSource=admin&retryWrites=true&w=majority",
```